# How to map same TO to new same TO in MapStruct?

Tags: java, mapstruct

My TO structure is as follows

```
OneComplexCto
-List<ComplexEto>
--List<SimpleEto>
```

I want to get it mapped with itself (for firing ValueChangeListener)

So I want to map like,

```
OneComplexCto mapOneComplexCto(OneComplexCto source, @TargetMapping OneComplexCto target);
```

It's just mapping like,

```
oneComplexCto.setComplexEtos(target.getComplexEtos);
```

and I want it to map all the nasted ComplexEto's and all the SimpleEto's inside those ComplexEto's. (Aparently I want to call the setters for each individual fields).

Answer (score 1):

As you've noticed MapStruct will just invoke the setter in case the types are the same. In order to achieve a deep clone you would need to deifine mapping between all the types. In your case this would look like:

```
@Mapper
public interface ComplexMapper {

    OneComplexCto mapOneComplexCto(OneComplexCto source, @MappingTarget OneComplexCto target);

    List<ComplexEto> map(List<ComplexEto> complexEtos);

    ComplexEto map(ComplexEto complexEto);

    List<SimpleEto> map(List<SimpleEto> simpleEtos);

    SimpleEto map(SimpleEto simpleEto);
}
```

You should follow and upvote [mapstruct/mapstruct-695](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/695) which looking for something to allow MapStruct to disable the direct set of the same types and perform deep clone.